# How to fix LinkageError occurred while loading main class error? Using an other JDK runtime?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, build, environment-variables

I want to start a Java ChatServer in IntelliJ (The Gradle JVM is set to Java 16.0.1 supposed to be!).
After running the Class I get the following error:

```
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class edu.hm.cs.vt.chat.server.ChatServerStarter
        java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: edu/hm/cs/vt/chat/server/ChatServerStarter has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 60.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    
    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':chat:server:ChatServerStarter.main()'. Process 'command '/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

My local configurations are set as followed:

Java Version:

```
java -version
openjdk version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14

which java
/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/bin/java
```

It seems that my Java Version is used from conda.

Java Versions installed on machine:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
16.0.1 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "OpenJDK 16.0.1" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
1.8.241.07 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java" /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
```

JAVA_HOME path:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Why does the

```
'/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/bin/java'
```

appears in the error-message??

How I can configure it to use the 16.0.1 JDK or what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways to do so ,

First is with gradle.properties you need to add

```
org.gradle.java.home=/path/to/jdk/directory
```

Second way is one time test with terminal like this

```
gradle build -Dorg.gradle.java.home=/JDK_PATH
```

3rd way you can add the path to build.gradle

```
 compileJava.options.fork = true
 compileJava.options.forkOptions.executable = '/path_to_javac'
```